# android retrofit 2 image upload

Tags: java, android, retrofit2

my api

```
  http://192.168.0.2/littlezebra/scripts/webservice.php?Case=updateProfile&user_id=1&profile_picture=happychild.png
```

how to in @Query send this

Comment: https://medium.com/@adinugroho/upload-image-from-android-app-using-retrofit-2-ae6f922b184c

Comment: not only for image that same time user id send how

Answer (score 0):

Retrofit interface:

```
@Multipart
@POST("upload/chatImage")
fun uploadChatImage(@Part file: MultipartBody.Part, @Query("something") something: String): Single<UploadedImage>
```

Usage:

```
fun uploadChatImage(uri: String?): Single<UploadedImage> {
    val picture = File(uri)
    val requestFile = RequestBody.create(MediaType.parse("image/*"), picture)
    val body = MultipartBody.Part.createFormData("photo", picture.name, requestFile)
    return apiService.uploadChatImage(body, "something")
}
```

I used RxJava adapter for retrofit and kotlin language. You can do it the same way without RxJava and kotlin.